# Send push notification on web app after a user submits a form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

We have a web app that runs on ASP.Net web forms. A user goes to a landing page that ask for some info, and it gets stored on a SQL data table and triggers and email notification to the contact center.

We need, that when some user sumbits the form the contact center agents recieve a push notification from the browser.

The landing page is located at an specific URL, let's say www.mysite.com/landing.aspx and the contact center's front is at www.mysite.com/admin

So far, we've tried using javascript. We have a code that search on the database for new records every minute, but it's loading the server with too much work!

This is the javascript that loads after the one minute task is executed:

```
    window.onload = function notifyMe() {
        // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification("New form request received!");
        }

        // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
        else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
                if (permission === "granted") {
                    var notification = new Notification("New form request received!");
                }
            });
        }

        // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
        // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
    }
</script>
```

Do you know a better way to achive this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SignalR for real time interactions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/signalr-chat-app-with-asp-net-webform-and-bootstrap/